# In Angular Service is not returning any value

Tags: angular, api, service

My API is fine, when browsed through Browser returning the Desired values.

But when I call the API in Service of angular it is not returning any value.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated, as I am stuck for two days now.

Below is my Service and Component Code.

Service.ts File

```
getStudentList(): Observable<IStudent[]>{
return this._http.get<IStudent[]>(this.ApiUrl);
}
```

Component.ts File

```
StudentList:IStudent[] ;


constructor(private _StudentService:SharedService) {
this.StudentList=[
  //  {Id:1,Name:'Pradeep',Age:29},
  //  {Id:2,Name:'Rakesh',Age:35}
]
```

}

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 //service call should always be done in ngOnInit
this._StudentService.getStudentList().subscribe(data => this.StudentList = data);
```

}

Comment: Can you check the network tab in chrome developer tools to check if api call is going or not. If yes then check for errors. Possibly its cross origin issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to catch erro that can happens in your API call :

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
        //service call should always be done in ngOnInit
       this._StudentService
       .getStudentList().
       subscribe(data => {
         console.log('data received',data);
         this.StudentList = data
         
       },err =>{
         console.log('err getting students data',err)
       });
```

}

Comment: The Actual Error I am getting is      `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:62964/api/Student' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Beshambher Chaukhwan, @Rebai Ahmed for guiding me the right path.

Also follow this link for more clarifications:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsnuIZX1C9A&t=282s

I figured out the issue, it was related with CORS .
Here is my solution:
i) Install CORS nuget Package in API Application.
ii) In WebApiConfig.cs file add following codes:
Add `using System.Web.Http.Cors;`
Inside Register Method add:
`EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); config.EnableCors(cors); //EnableCorsAttribute("URL","Header","Methods(ex. Get,Put etc")`